# re-execute document.ready after reload partialview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First time everything is works fine and `$(document).ready` function calls in `_EditPhoneNBR.cshtml`.

In `$(document).ready` I change mask for textboxes dynamically. In  `_EditPhone.cshtml` when I select country dropdown change I call ajax method and reload the `_EditPhoneNBR.cshtml` and return data I need to change textboxes masks.

But it is not working. Is there any alternative I can do this?. I tried all possible ways, not succeeded.

### _EditPhone.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmPhone", id = "frmPhone" }))
 {
         <tr>
           <td>@Html.Label("Country:", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
             <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CommunicationCountry,
                            AppCountryCodeList,
                            "Select",
                                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }
                    )                           
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Phone Number", new { @class = "control-label" })</td>
                    <td >
                        <div id="DivPhoneNBRContainer">
                            @Html.Partial("_EditPhoneNBR", Model)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

        //jquery is for user select a new country
    $('#CommunicationCountry').change(function(){
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'customer/CountryChange',
                    type: "Get",
                    data: { id: $("#CommunicationCountry").val() },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#DivPhoneNBRContainer").empty();
                        $('#DivPhoneNBRContainer').html(data);                           
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                });            
        });
</script>
```

### _EditPhoneNBR.cshtml

```
   @Html.TextBox("phonecountrycode", Model.PhoneCountryCode, new { @class = "spe_comm_country", @Readonly = "readonly" })
   @Html.TextBox("Space1", ".", new { @class = "spe_space_10" })
   @Html.TextBox("phoneareacode", Model.PhoneAreaCode, new { @class = "spe_comm_AreaCode" })
   @Html.TextBox("Space2", ".", new { @class = "spe_space_10", @readonly = "readonly" })
   @Html.TextBox("phonenumber", Model.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "spe_comm_phonenumber" })
   @Html.TextBox("Space1", "Ext", new { @class = "spe_space_30", @readonly = "readonly" })
   @Html.TextBox("phoneextension", Model.PhoneExtension, new { @class = "spe_comm_phoneext" })

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var COUNTRY_CODE_format = $("#PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE_format").val();
        var AREA_CODE_format = $("#PHONE_AREA_CODE_format").val();
        var NUMBER_format = $("#PHONE_NUMBER_format").val();  
        var EXTENSION_format = $("#PHONE_EXTENSION_format").val();

        if (COUNTRY_CODE_format != "") {
            $('#phonecountrycode').mask(COUNTRY_CODE_format);
        }
        if (AREA_CODE_format != "") {           
            $('#phoneareacode').mask(AREA_CODE_format);
        }
        if (NUMBER_format != "") {
            $('#phonenumber').mask(NUMBER_format);
        }
        if (EXTENSION_format != ""){
            $('#phoneextension').mask(EXTENSION_format);       
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put the js code from the partial in a function, and call this in the success of the Ajax Get. Any function in the partial should be available in the "parent", and this is a technique I use myself.

In the partial view:

```
function initEditPhoneNBR() {
    var COUNTRY_CODE_format = $("#PHONE_COUNTRY_CODE_format").val();
    var AREA_CODE_format = $("#PHONE_AREA_CODE_format").val();
    var NUMBER_format = $("#PHONE_NUMBER_format").val();  
    var EXTENSION_format = $("#PHONE_EXTENSION_format").val();

    if (COUNTRY_CODE_format != "") {
        $('#phonecountrycode').mask(COUNTRY_CODE_format);
    }
    if (AREA_CODE_format != "") {           
        $('#phoneareacode').mask(AREA_CODE_format);
    }
    if (NUMBER_format != "") {
        $('#phonenumber').mask(NUMBER_format);
    }
    if (EXTENSION_format != ""){
        $('#phoneextension').mask(EXTENSION_format);       
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    initEditPhoneNBR();
});
```

In the ajax, parent view:

```
$('#CommunicationCountry').change(function(){
         $.ajax({
                url: 'customer/CountryChange',
                type: "Get",
                data: { id: $("#CommunicationCountry").val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#DivPhoneNBRContainer").empty();
                    $('#DivPhoneNBRContainer').html(data);
                    initEditPhoneNBR();                         
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });            
    });
```

Comment: initEditPhoneNBR();  In the ajax, parent view. not firing. looks like after `$('#DivPhoneNBRContainer').html(data);` control is not coming back.

Comment: @James123 Your controller action is returning a PartialView, right?

Comment: Yes, `return PartialView("_EditPhoneNBR", memberphone);`

Comment: and parentview also a partialview.

Comment: @James123 Is there no model defined by the partial (_EditPhoneNBR)? Like `@model Model.MemberPhone`

Comment: yes, @model Model.Models.MemberCommunications. which is `memberphone`

Comment: @James123 if, as you say "control is not coming back" after loading the partial, I suppose there must be some error in the partial that halts further execution. If you placed an `alert()` right after `$('#DivPhoneNBRContainer').html(data);`, does it not fire?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74505/discussion-between-james123-and-mackan).